# How do I get email notifications of new replies to my question?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, email-notification

Is there is a way I could get email notifications of new replies to my questions posted on Stack Exchange?

I have searched about this question already and can't find the options mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Only if you don't click your inbox in Stack Exchange itself. If you click it, you can't get email. The email you can get is described in the dupe.